# Split single ceiling fan into two

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I am probably overthinking this, but since I'm more of a carpenter and less of an electrician I thought I best ask for help to make sure.  I have two rooms in my house that are 15 x 30 and only have a single ceiling fan/light in the middle of the room.  I'm thinking I'd like to split that line into two ceiling fans, one on each side of the room.  They wouldn't be running simultanesouly (at least not very often), but even with the lights on, the edges of the rooms are dark and I have my office along the outer wall so having the extra light without lamps everywhere would be nice. 1) Is this something I can do? and 2) how do I do the wiring?  I've done basic wiring several times before, so I'm not entirely a newbie, but I just don't want to burn my house down...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the existing ceiling fans controlled?

Comment: If you want extra light then install extra lights. Ceiling light fixtures are simpler to install and more subtle than a whole fan.

Comment: Do you have a two story house? If so are these rooms on the bottom floor?